# Change property of component from template based on parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates

I want to use the **same style** for two controls, just change two background colors that are deep in its hierarchy.

I have a `TextBox`, a style for its `ScrollViewer`, a style and a template for its `ScrollBar` with a `Background` for its Border and a style for its `Thumb` with a `Background` for its Border.

How can I change The two backgrounds (programmatically or not) using only the TextBox?

.........
        
            ..........
                        
            ..........

```
<!-- ScrollBar Style -->
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="ScrollBar">
        ....
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                ....
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarTemplate}"/>
                ....
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<!-- Horizontal Scrollbar Template -->
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Grid Background="{StaticResource ScrollBackroundBrush}">
            <Track Name="PART_Track">
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"/>
                </Track.Thumb>
            </Track>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>

<!-- Thumb Style -->
    <Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
....
        <Setter Property="Template">
            ....
                    <Border
                        ....
                        Background="{StaticResource ScrollThumbBrush}"/>
           ....
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Is there a way to change the two backgrounds (to use **this** color and another same scrollviewer on another control perhaps with **another** color) without *rewriting* the whole code?

For example to have its style and write:

```
TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
tb1.Style = /*style*/
tb1.BackgroundOfScroll = /*brush11*/
tb1.BackgroundOfThumb = /*brush12*/


TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
tb2.Style = /*style*/
tb2.BackgroundOfScroll = /*brush21*/
tb2.BackgroundOfThumb = /*brush22*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made corresponding example. If you had only one color to set you could use *Tag* property since it is *DependencyProperty*. Create then two attached properties and get to them as follows:

```
 <Button local:Color.CustomBackground="CadetBlue">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                                <Border Width="50" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}"
                                        Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=(local:Color.CustomBackground)}">

                                </Border>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
```

C#

```
 public class Color : DependencyObject
    {
        private static readonly DependencyProperty CustomBackgroundProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("CustomBackground", typeof(SolidColorBrush), typeof(Color),
                new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static void SetCustomBackground(DependencyObject obj, SolidColorBrush color)
        {
            obj.SetValue(CustomBackgroundProperty, color);
        }

        public static SolidColorBrush GetCustomBackground(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (SolidColorBrush)obj.GetValue(CustomBackgroundProperty);
        }
    }
```