# Use the same template but a different value for a property

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, styles

Is there a way to use the same style/template for two controls but with a modified property without rewriting the whole code? For example two ScrollViewers with the same style or template but with a different background.

It's related to my other question: [Change property of component from template based on parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067775/change-property-of-component-from-template-based-on-parent)

Comment: See [Style.BasedOn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It doesn't help me here because I still need to rewrite the whole **template** just to change a background color.

Comment: Can you show your template?

Comment: See it from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27067775/change-property-of-component-from-template-based-on-parent. The background colors I need to change are deep in the **template of templates** and i want to use the *same* template just with different *colors*. I tried the TemplateBinding but it doesn't work for a template in templates.. i can't quite explaint it..

Comment: I ended up understanding the answer given http://stackoverflow.com/a/27069429/1992635 here and using that, if fit up nicely! Your `BasedOn` comment really helped me as well and it's actually a direct answer to my current question so go ahead and make it an answer and I'll approve it.